# Checking degenerate and non degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

in $P_n, w(x,y) = x(1) y(1)$
How to check whether it is degenerate or non-degenerate?
I know how to show it is a bilinear form. If it is non-degenerate, I give out a case in which $w(x,y) \ne 0$ . Am not sure whether I am on the right track or not. Please explain me.